# http post method passing multiple json parameters with alamofire in swift 2.0

Tags: swift

**strong text** this is my code to pass two parameters(jsonData and device_Secret) to httpBody for that i should get following son in response

```
{"success":false,"msg":"Key not created plz try again."}
```

but i m getting this

```
responseString = Optional({"success":false,"msg":"Invalid Method"})
```

there is a problem in parameters format, what i am doing wrong?
my code is following /////////////

```
let JsonData  = ["method":"device_token","params":["key":"1234jhg","device_id":"eb7e630a9637b0b83557e5a62121be8cb9210afb9aa5b878f819b775cb7d42a6"]]

        let device_secret  = ["params":["token":"-1","device_id":"9de47fb53c67eca4","key":"-1"]]
        let params = ["data":JsonData, "device_secret":device_secret] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>


        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://dev.jobsmarket.pk/api/v1")!)
        print(request)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"


        let data : NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(params)
        print("NSdata of params is")
        print(data)




        NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(params)
        print( NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(params))
        //            request.HTTPBody = params
        request.HTTPBody = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(params)
        print("httpBody is ")
        print(request.HTTPBody)


        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil && data != nil else {                                                          // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")
        }
        task.resume()
```

/////////////////////////

Comment: Why are you calling `NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(params)` instead of `NSJSONSerialization` stuff?

Comment: to convert NSdictionary to NSdata

Comment: Try NJSOnSerialization instead....

Comment: have tried it facing the same problem

Comment: You tried with `let json = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dic, options: .prettyPrinted); request.HTTPBody = json`?

Comment: yes, n it has the same response, it has some other problem.
i have to send form data with key and value

Comment: If you print param, is it the same format as asked by your WebService?

Comment: yes i have checked it is the same format

Comment: key:data,value:{"method":"device_token","params":{"key":"1234ff","device_id":"eb7e630a9637b0b83557e5a62121be8cb9210afb9aa5b878f819b775cb7d42a6"}} 
this is my first son object 
key:device_secret,value:{"params":{"token":"-1","device_id":"9de47fb53c67eca4","key":"-1"}}
above is my second json object, could you please write them in swift format, ia m only having problem with them